# Nanoscroller doesn't create a scroll if the content is inserted after the scroller is initiated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [nanoscroller js](https://github.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS) to create a scrollable area in a `div` element. The problem is that I'm filling that `div` element with data with ajax (imagine facebook notifications). First there are 0 notifications, no data. Then I fill it with 10. The scrollbar isn't there. When I refresh the page (with 10 notifications now already there), it creates itself, because it knows there is more content than there is room.

How can I make it create the scroller when the data is filled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reinitialize the nanoScroller $("your scrollable").nanoScroller(); after you inserted the content...

like

```
$("your content div").append("something");
$("your scrollable container").nanoScroller();
```

Answer (score 2):

@Jonatas Answer didn't work with me, then I figured out this one

`$("#my_scrollable_container")[0].nanoscroller.reset();`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My nano div originally fills the width of the screen and the amount of content does not require a scrollbar. But then a user action causes a second div to appear on the right side, making the nano div skinner and too small to display all the content -- but the scrollbar didn't appear (although I could still use the mouse wheel to scroll the nano content).

Neither of the answers provided worked for me, or maybe I applied them incorrectly. So I looked in the jquery.nanoscroller.js code (which I guess is what I should have done in the first place) and found the call is just:

> $(".nano").nanoScroller();

No need to reference the div ID or anything. Each time the size of your nano div is changed, make this call and the nano scrollbar should adjust to fit. And if you have multiple nano divs in the page, this one call will reset all of them.

Comment: That's essentially the same as Jonatas' answer.

Answer (score 0):

beware of use such a kinda :
 
`$(".nano").nanoScroller();`

cause if U have a lot of .nano DIV's and U Ajaxing data to ONE of them, 
better use for example:

`$("#FaceBookAjaxNotifi .nano").nanoScroller();`
as Jonatas wrote..

**(it boost performance dramatically in some situations)**